# google maps custom control position - BOTTOM_RIGHT not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made a custom control in google maps and i'm trying to position it on the BOTTOM_RIGHT corner of the screen. When the page initially loads for the first time it is placed correctly and works fine. However as soon as I drag the map, the control is moved to center of the screen.
Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Perhaps i could add a listener on dragstart and replace the control every time? Not sure how to do this though...

```
  var leyendDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
  var leyendControl = new LeyendControl(leyendDiv);
  leyendDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT].push(leyendDiv);
```

any advice is very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed today, 30 June 2011, by the update to Google Maps Api V3. Change log is here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog

Answer (score 1):

Even though the page in v3 changelog said its fixed.
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog

as of Nov 8, 2012, its broken again.
the best we can do at the moment is to use BOTTOM_CENTER

I think Google doesn't want to block the **Terms of use** link on the bottom right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:-

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(leyendDiv);
```